# failed to open stream using include

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

This is a simple question that is already there in stack overflow but I tried all the possible answers and it's still not fixed.

I need to include the config file which is under the assets folder. I tried the following code:

```
include_once '../config.php' ;
```

I am getting errors like this:

```
Warning: include(assets/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\project\assets\handler\ContactHandler.php on line 4

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'assets/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in E:\xampp\htdocs\project\assets\handler\ContactHandler.php on line 4
```

Kindly suggest me a possible way to include a config file in ContactHandler.php

ContachHandler.php

```
<?php

include_once 'E:\xampp\htdocs\project\assets\config.php';

echo "ddddd";
exit;
 include (CONTROLLER.'ContactController.php');
$form = $_POST['form'];
$cnt_controller = new ContactController();
switch ($form)

{

    case 'AddContact':
        $cnt_controller->AddContact($_POST);
        break;
    case 'ContactUs':
    $cnt_controller->ContactUs($_POST);
        break;

}



?>
```

Comment: your file path is not correct

Comment: include_once '../../config.php' ; try this

Comment: Either `include_once '../../config.php' ;` Or `include_once '../assets/config.php' ;`

Comment: @vimal Give permission to your folder if the path is correct.

Comment: I have given all permission to the folders @NithinJohn still i can't include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if your include path changed and check file/folder permissions.

Try out this code:

```
<?php
$config_path = '../config.php' ;
if (file_exists($config_path)){
    require_once $config_path;
}
else {
    $config_path = 'config.php';
    if (file_exists($config_path)) {
        require_once $config_path;
    }
    else {
        $config_path = '../../config.php';
        require_once $config_path;
    }
}

echo "ddddd";
echo $config_path;
exit;
?>
```

For testing set static path:

```
include_once 'E:\xampp\htdocs\project\assets\config.php';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Shafiqul it's entering to the if condition it means the file exists but am getting page isn't working error

Comment: for testing 

include_once 'E:\xampp\htdocs\project\assets\config.php';
add this

Comment: still, it shows the same error, the code is correct and the file exists inside the assets still some problem occurs in including the file

Comment: Actually, it's entering the if condition I gave echo"ddd"; before require once of the if condition it stops there and printing ddd if I remove the echo it show's the same error page Isn't working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148293/discussion-between-shafiqul-islam-and-vimal-kumar).